# Azure Form Recognizer mainline support for Office documents

Tags: azure, ocr, azure-form-recognizer

I have been using the `2022/06/30-preview` version of the API to OCR-ize docx and powerpoint documents.
Now that the API has been stabilized and has moved to `2022-08-31`, I have updated my code to use this stable version (juste a version update of the sdk client), but the same documents are now rejected, with an error `InvalidContent`, `"The file is corrupted or format is unsupported. Refer to documentation for the list of supported formats."`.

Has support for Office documents been dropped or is there some settings to add ? From [the changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/whats-new?view=form-recog-3.0.0&tabs=csharp) I don't seem to see any mention that support has been dropped between the last preview version and the stable one.

I'm using the node.js SDK. I have checked that the same docx document, using the same exact code, is accepted using the `@azure/ai-form-recognizer@4.0.0-beta.5` SDK client, but not the latest and stable `@azure/ai-form-recognizer@4.0.0` version. The code I'm using is almost exactly the example code in the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/get-started-sdks-rest-api?view=form-recog-3.0.0&pivots=programming-language-javascript), only the urls change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Well according to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/concept-read?view=form-recog-3.0.0#:%7E:text=%E2%9C%B1%20microsoft%20office%20files%20are%20currently%20not%20supported%20for%20other%20models%20or%20versions.) they have dropped support for Microsoft office files for all SDK.
- So, you have two options the form recognizer does provide support but for Microsoft office files through [RestAPi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=form-recog-3.0.0&preserve-view=true&tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-rest-api). So, you can either make http calls or you can convert the files to pdf and then use conventional SDK for further processing.
- The conversion is done using [docx-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-pdf) npm package. Here I have a `hjh.docx` which I am converting to `pdfuploader.pdf` and then processing it.

```
const  fs = require("fs");
const { AzureKeyCredential, DocumentAnalysisClient } = require("@azure/ai-form-recognizer");

const key= "";
const endpoint = "";

async  function  main() {
    //convertion logic 
    var  docxConverter = require('docx-pdf');
    docxConverter('./hjh.docx','./pdfuploader.pdf',function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('result'+result);
    });

    // form recognizer logic

    const  client = new  DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint, new  AzureKeyCredential(key));
    const  readStream = fs.createReadStream("<Path>");
    const  poller = await  client.beginAnalyzeDocument("prebuilt-document", readStream,{
        onProgress: ({ status }) => {
            console.log(`status: ${status}`);
        },
    });
    const  e = await  poller.pollUntilDone();
    console.log(e);
    
}
main().catch((error) => {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

`@azure/ai-form-recognizer` output:
[image]

`@azure/ai-form-recognizer@4.0.0-beta.5` output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It was not clear to me if this meant that they had dropped support or just postponed it for a next release. Also it's not clear if the preview will stay available and I can use it, or if it will be dropped sometimes as the API will go forward.